# Prove that g(y)>0 for all y in the real numbers

Tags: functions

Let g:$\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ such that

($i$) for all $y_{1},y_{2} \in \mathbb{R}$,  $g(y_{1}+y_{2}$)=$g(y_{1})g(y_{2})$

suppose in addition that

($ii$) there exists $y \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $g(y)\neq 0$

I am trying to prove that $(\forall y\in\mathbb{R})(g(y)>0)$

I already know that

1. $g(0)=1$
2. $g(y) \neq 0$ and $g(-y) = 1/g(y)$
3. $g(y_{1}-y_{2})=g(y_{1})/g(y_{2})$
4. $g(2y) = g(y)^{2}$

I have one thought but I am not sure if it is even accurate.  By (2) we know that plugging in a negative number gives us a positive number. It seems important, but if $g(y)$ is negative then $g(-y)$ is also negative.  So what should I try?  I can't seem to think of anything else.

Comment: Are you sure that *(i)* is only given for $y_1,y_2\in(0,\infty)$? In that case $g(x)=x-|x|$ is a solution for which the claim does not hold.

Comment: You were right, I fixed that in the question.

Comment: like logarithm: $\log_a b$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $g(y_0)=0$ for some $y_0$, then $g(y)=g(y-y_0+y_0)=g(y-y_0)g(y_0)=0$ for all $y$.
Hence, $g(y)\ne0$ for all $y$.

Then, $g(y)=g\left(\dfrac y2+\dfrac y2\right)=g\left(\dfrac y2\right)^2 >0$

Answer (score 0):

#### Seems similar to logarithms *$\log_a b$* properties.

1. $\log_b 1 = 0$
2. $\log_b 0$ - not defined
3. $\log_b x - \log_b y = log_b \frac{x}{y}$
4. $2 \cdot log_b x = log_b x^2$

> *The limit of the base $b$ logarithm of $x$,
>
>   when $x$ approaches zero from the positive side (0+), is minus infinity $-\infty$ :*
>   $$\lim_{x\to{0+}} \log_b(x) = -\infty$$

[image]

--

> **Bibliography:**
>  [Logarithm - Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia](http://goo.gl/hdF3J)
>  [Why logarithm of zero, log(0), is not defined?](http://goo.gl/MkzNkP)
>  [What does ln(0)=? | Natural logarithm of zero](http://goo.gl/tJpB9D)
>  [List of logarithmic identities - Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia](http://goo.gl/OFdLKT)